# Как спарсить цены с Торговой Площадки Стим?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, steam, site

У меня есть список url скинов из игры CS2.(Пример: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Desert%20Eagle%20%7C%20Urban%20DDPAT%20%28Factory%20New%29) Мне нужно спарсить минимальную цену за которую продают этот скин и максимальную цену за которую готовы купить этот скин (Обведены на скриншоте).Просто спарсить через requests не получается, так как сайт прогружается постепенно и если делать запросы часто то сайт совсем не показывает цены. Selenium меня не устраивает. Так же я пробовал код из это GitHub: https://github.com/ByMykel/CSGO-API , но после 5-7 запросов он переставал работать выдавая ошибку. Видимо связано со стимом. Прокси так же не помогал. Подскажите, что можно сделать в этой ситуации. Заранее, спасибо. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример ссылки с которой нужно спарсить цену, пожалуйста.

Comment: Здравствуйте, пример ссылки добавлен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороший ответ дан [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917088/how-to-scrape-multiple-webpages-stemming-from-one-page-using-selenium). Я написал упрощенный код для парсинга цен через имя. Как и сказано в том вопросе лучше добавлять задержки между запросами иначе стим может заблокировать их на определённый таймаут.

```py
import re
import time

import requests


def parse(name):
    name_id_response = requests.get(f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/{name}")
    name_id = re.search(r"Market_LoadOrderSpread\( (?P<item_id>\d+) \)", name_id_response.text).group("item_id")

    time.sleep(1)

    response = requests.get(f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=US&"
                            f"language=russian&currency=1&item_nameid={name_id}&two_factor=0").json()

    return int(response["highest_buy_order"]) / 100, int(response["lowest_sell_order"]) / 100


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = "Desert%20Eagle%20%7C%20Urban%20DDPAT%20%28Factory%20New%29"

    print(parse(name))
```